# Spark (Scala): Rogue '%' sign from println of dataframe count()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, println

I'm working with the [Yelp Academic Dataset](https://www.yelp.com/dataset) and I've taken a small sample of the review samples to determine the number of distinct, reviewed businesses on a small scale.

```
val distinctReviewedBusinesses = reviewsDataFrame.select("business_id").distinct()
print("Number of distinct, reviewed businesses: " + distinctReviewedBusinesses.count())
```

I'm not asking for solution to the problem, but about a bug with the output, which has a rogue percent-sign '%' (as seen below). What business does it have being there?

> Number of distinct, reviewed businesses: 6600%

And in the image below, you can see that, for some reason, the percent-sign is highlighted.

[image]

- Scala: v2.11.8
- Spark: v2.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you’re using zsh. In zsh, that symbol indicates that the last line of output has no terminating newline. This happens because you are using print instead of println. See [more on SuperUser](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/why-zsh-ends-a-line-with-a-highlighted-percent-symbol).

Comment: I was using println, but you guessed zsh, so you got to the crux of the problem